# Are there any languages that place subjects and direct objects before the verbs, but everything else after?

Tags: grammar, linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, word-order

I know the Romance languages do this with pronouns, but they don't do this with noun phrases.

Are there any natlangs out there where the subject and direct object always precedes the verb, but everything else comes after it?

Comment: In languages where the subject and object always precede the verb (SOV languages; there are quite a lot), it is usually the case that everything else also precedes the verb as well. I.e, the verb is almost always the last word in the sentence. In what order all this stuff goes before the verb at the end, and how it's marked, gets to be quite complex.

Comment: As far as I know, it's somewhat rare for languages to have only one completely fixed order for S, O, V and other elements of a clause that is used in all clauses. Is the "always" part of this question important, or are you really just looking for a language where this word order is common and "unmarked"?

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: I don't actually know that much, so I wanted to add that you shouldn't consider my comment reliable. I definitely might be wrong. The SOVX word order of Mande that user6726's answer mentions is apparently [quite rigid](http://www.academia.edu/20466872/Categorial_reanalysis_and_the_origin_of_the_S-O-V-X_word_order_in_Mande), anyway, so the answer works either way

Answer (score 5):

[Mande languages](http://mandelang.kunstkamera.ru/files/mandelang/nikitina_tezis.pdf) generally have SOVX word order. Otherwise, it is quite rare.